# Conversão de números

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Como faço a conversão de um número `float` para ficar com as características de números para o usuário final ler?

Estou montando um relatório e desejo fazer a tratativa dos números. 
Tenho um campo em que o valor está `194728472.48274487`

Quero deixar ele organizado parecido com:
`1.947.284,33` e assim por diante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente pode usar a função [format](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

Utilizando o seu exemplo:

```
format (194728472.48274487, 'c', 'pt-br')
```

Confira um exemplo criado no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10c4e/2), vendo sua aplicação em um cenário de teste.

---

**Edit (SQLServer 2008):**
Fiz vários testes, usando `convert`, `replace` e cast de maneira simples na consulta, mas não obtive sucesso também, acessei essa função para resolver o seu problema:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatDinheiro(@Valor DECIMAL(20, 2))
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS BEGIN
DECLARE
@ValorStr VARCHAR(30),
@Inteiro VARCHAR(30),
@Decimal VARCHAR(3),
@I INT,
@Count INT,
@IntLen INT

SET @ValorStr = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @Valor)

SET @ValorStr = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(@ValorStr, '.', '')))
SET @ValorStr = REPLACE(@ValorStr, ',', '')
SET @Inteiro = ''

IF (Len(@ValorStr) = 1)
BEGIN
SET @Inteiro = '0'
SET @Decimal = '0'+@ValorStr
END
ELSE
BEGIN
IF (Len(@ValorStr) = 2)
BEGIN
SET @Inteiro = '0'
SET @Decimal = @ValorStr
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @Decimal = Substring(@ValorStr, (Len(@ValorStr)-1), Len(@ValorStr))
SET @I = 3
SET @Count = 0
WHILE (@I <= Len(@ValorStr))
BEGIN
IF (@Count = 3)
BEGIN
SET @Inteiro = '.'+@Inteiro
SET @Count = 0
END
SET @IntLen = (Len(@ValorStr)+1)-@I
IF (@IntLen >= 0)
BEGIN
SET @Inteiro = Substring(@ValorStr, @IntLen, 1)+@Inteiro
END
SET @I = @I + 1
SET @Count = @Count + 1
END
END
END
IF (@Inteiro = '') SET @Inteiro = '0'
IF (@Decimal = '') SET @Decimal = '00'
RETURN @Inteiro+','+@Decimal
END
GO
```

<sub>Autor: [Elton Bicalho do Carmo](http://eltonbicalho.blogspot.com/2010/08/formatar-dinheiro-no-sql-server.html)</sub>

Comment: O comando FORMAT não funciona no SQL Server, infelizmente!

Comment: Qual a versão do seu SQLServer?

Comment: É o SQL Server 2008

Comment: @JulioCesarAndrade, alterei a resposta, tenta agora.

Comment: Outra questão, será que no seu relatório/aplicação não poderia formatar isso, pois usando a função, vai ficar um pouco mais pesado.